# os.listdir for path contain blank

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.path, listdir

this very weird problem my code works fine in my machine (Linux mint) but it shows error in my server

here's the code -note i've make it `abspath` even it was works fine without it in my machine !

```
def GET_Contents(filepath):
    return os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('files', filepath.strip())))
```

here's the the given exception 
`return os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('files', filepath.strip())))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hamoud/webapps/FileManager/files/EE201/MID 1'`

the problem occurs only with the folders that contains spaces (like `MID 1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are fine and allowed in Windows paths too.

You need to verify that your working directory is correct (since you use a relative path, `os.path.abspath()` will base the absolute path of the current working directory in that case).

If the base path is correct, check that there really *is* a `MID 1` directory at that location. Perhaps check the *parent* directory with `os.listdir(os.path.abspath('files'))` first to see what is really located there.

Comment: but that yield MID1 instead of MID 1 then that another file which it doesn't exist

Comment: @EngHamoud: Then it is not clear what you are asking. What folder *does* exist then?

Comment: @EngHamoud: Note the full path `os.path.abspath()` produces; you gave it a relative path (`files/EE201/MID 1`) so Python makes it a full path relative to the current working directory. If your files live *elsewhere* you need to give it the right absolute path.

Comment: @EngHamoud: I highly doubt it is the *spaces* in the path that are the cause here, unless your file paths don't actually contain spaces but other characters. What does `os.listdir()` for the **parent directory** show is in that directory?

Comment: oh yeah ,, thanks for pointing that out , it was `MID 1 ` so `os.listdir()` helps me a lot to figure it out , thanks change your answer so i could submit it as answer